# Can my hardware run Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-xp

I have Club3D Geforce fx5200 and Intel (r) Celeron (r) 2.80ghz
RAM 1G (Upgraded from 512mb) hdd 200gb, i can add more if i need. Do Ubuntu will work to me? My machine is running windows xp sp3. And i want to run Counter-Strike 1.6 [Steam] /w no glitches on it with ubuntu?

Comment: I'd recommend doing a dual boot with Windows and Ubuntu at first.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to most of the question: **Yes**.

Ubuntu will almost certainly work. You can test this by using a LiveCD/LiveUSB. If that works, Ubuntu'll work. You may need to install custom graphics drivers, though.

Regarding CounterStrike 1.6:

If it is Linux-native, sure. It should work well enough, provided your system has good specs.

If it is not Linux-native, you might have luck with WINE. However, this does not mean it will work. WINE (while good) is not perfect. There will almost always be something wrong. It might work, it might not. It really depends on how much WINE likes CounterStrike and vice versa.

> Comment-In-An-Answer:
>
> Try to install more RAM.